# Pass context value into firestore document add/set/update from Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I am looking to use the `https.onCall` to accept some input from a user (such as data about another user). I'd then like to do some advanced processing on that data including retrieving sensitive data from other entries on my firestore that should not be exposed. Depending on the outcome of that analysis, I will update other locations in the database. However, I am concerned about the security of the original call and its source. I know that I have the `context` parameter on the `onCall` to verify the source was logged in, but I'd like to apply security rules to the final write based on the `context.auth` provided to the cloud function.

The security rules are straight forward for normal database operations but not if I'm doing an operation (seeded by a normal user) routed through the Admin SDK.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'd like to apply security rules to the final write based on the context.auth provided to the cloud function

As you are aware that you can identify which user made a call to functions as well as that Admin SDK has super-access to database, the general flow should be to write functions in a way that they only edit documents that should be editable by the user.

If you had still like to narrow down access, you can do that for firebase database by passing [databaseAuthVariableOverride](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.AppOptions#optional-databaseauthvariableoverride) when initializing admin app.

[Read more on authenticating with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges)

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading it wrong but it looks like the "authenticating with limited privileges" is only available for Realtime Database? I don't see similar documentation in Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the admin SDK, or any of the server SDKs, it always bypasses all security rules.  Rules only apply to access coming directly from web and mobile clients using the client SDKs.

If you need to apply some sort or restricts to data written from your backend, you will need to code that into the logic of your backend code.  Security rules will be of no help.